# How to write a PIP extension in Java running on the WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, identity, xacml, wso2-identity-server

Found a reference article about how to write a XACML PIP extension in WSO2 under the link http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/04/xacml-policy-information-point.html

Is the list of prerequisites still valid for WSO2 Identity Server Version 5? The article mentions two .jars that are required, the 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-3.2.0.jar and the sun-xacml-2.0.1.wso2v1.jar. Is there a newer set available?

Could you please confirm where to obtain those jar files or give some updated link to the documentation.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Regards,
Claude

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There are newer versions for org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement jar.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-4.2.0.jar and org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-4.2.2.jar.

You can find org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-4.2.0.jar from [1].
org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement-4.2.2.jar is available in /repository/components/plugins.

You can find sun-xacml-2.0.1.wso2v1.jar from [2].

[1] http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/wso2maven2/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement/4.2.0/

[2] http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/sun-xacml/wso2/sun-xacml/2.0.1.wso2v1/